# shadow-cljs watch app error on luminus page

Tags: web, clojure, luminus

I am using luminus to build a webpage. I want to use clojure script so I created a project with

```
lein new luminus test +cljs
```

When starting the webpage I get the following message:

```
If you're seeing this message, that means you haven't yet compiled your ClojureScript!

Please run shadow-cljs watch app to start the ClojureScript compiler and reload the page.
```

so I installed and tried to run

```
npx shadow-cljs watch app
```

and get the following error:

```
shadow-cljs - config: /Users/jonas/Dropbox/prog/web/clojure/luminus/test/shadow-cljs.edn
shadow-cljs - running: lein with-profile +dev run -m shadow.cljs.devtools.cli --npm watch app
Executable 'lein' not found on system path.
```

i've looked everywhere but I cannot solve this problem. Any ideas?

update:

ok, this is what I have done to temporarily solve this:

First install in the test dir:

```
npm install react react-dom create-react-class
```

then run lein directly:

`lein with-profile +dev run -m shadow.cljs.devtools.cli --npm watch app`

so it is not suppose to be like this, but this is the closest that I get.

Comment: What operating system are you on? If "lein new luminus test +cljs" worked for you then you should not get this error "Executable 'lein' not found on system path."

Comment: I am on ubuntu. "lein new luminus test +cljs" creates all files but gives the above error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I looked after a path variable to set but could not find one. So I simply copied lein from ~/bin/lein (my home dir) to /usr/local/bin and now it found it and it works.
Strange that there is no way to set this for shadow